# Empty runlist when running chef-client from node

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm not sure why at this point but after knife bootsrapping a new node the node seems to loose it's run list. sshing to the node, if I run chef-client it dumps all the cookbooks I just bootstrapped it with and says it's has an empty run list:

```
...
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Removing cookbooks/nfs/.kitchen.yml.aws from the cache; its cookbook is no longer needed on this client.
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Removing cookbooks/users/.foodcritic from the cache; its cookbook is no longer needed on this client.
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Removing     cookbooks/java/.rubocop_todo.yml from the cache; its cookbook is no     longer needed on this client.
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] WARN: Node app-test004 has an empty run list.
Converging 0 resources
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.229085419 seconds

Running handlers:
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Running report handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-03-19T14:39:21-04:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

This is on one of two new chef servers and the other is behaving correctly. Any ideas on what to look for?

Comment: What commands are you executing?

Comment: once ssh'd to the node? just chef-client

Comment: No command line arguments of any kind? Also how are you running the bootstrap?

Comment: knife bootstrap root@10.0.1.1 -i dev.pem -policy-group dev -policyfile dev-app

Comment: figured out the problem - my cookbook appears to be successfully finishing but actually is not. So when I jump on the node and run chef-client the run list is not set. For some reason a ruby block at the end of my recipe is interfering with the chef run... looks like it's taking over the ruby version running and can't hand back over to the chef version once the block has executed.